# Is this Java Enumeration Used/Designed Correctly?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, enums

I was tasked with converting some Java code to C# and came across the following enumeration (I had to generalize it, because the code is proprietary, sorry). The general purpose of the code is to convert from a "non-base unit" to a "base unit" (like converting from say kilometers to millimeters, or whatever. They have a ton of conversions). The only things I changed were the variable names. The pattern is exactly like this in the code...

```
public enum ThisIsAnEnum implements someInterface
{        
    typeKilom( MetricType.kilometer ),

    typeMillm( MetricType.millimeter );

    public double convertSomething(double dbl1, double dbl2)
    {
        // do stuff
        return a double
    }
}
```

This is then called in the code as follows:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ThisIsAnEnum.typeKilom.convertSomething(aDouble, bDouble);
}
```

I have a couple questions:

- Is this use of enumerations a good practice in Java?
- If yes or if no, what approach should I take in C#? Can you do something similar? Even if I can, I'm not sure that this approach is correct.

I'm not asking for someone to convert this for me... just whether this is a good approach and (if so) should I try to do the same thing in C#. If it's not, then what approach should be taken?

Comment: Well this is simply a difference in how enums work in Java/C#.

Comment: @codroipo I was planning on just doing that, but in my limited knowledge of C# I thought I'd see if there was a more elegant approach.

Comment: `new ThisIsAnEnum();`: you cannot create such [new instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851377/instantiate-enum-class). Does this code compile?

Comment: Can this help you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx

Comment: @CommuSoft You know what you are right. Let me edit how its used.

Comment: @CommuSoft I edited it. That's how the previous developer showed me it was used. That did compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of java enums is a subjective question that I'm not well qualified to answer.  I can say that you could solve your problem in C# using an extension method though.  I'm not sure what relevance the interface has, but given what you've shown, you can reproduce it like this.

```
void Main() {
    ThisIsAnEnum.typeKilom.ConvertSomething(1, 2);
}

public enum ThisIsAnEnum {
    typeKilom,
    typeMillm,
}

public static class ThisIsAnEnumExtensions {
    // extension method
    public static double ConvertSomething(this ThisIsAnEnum @this, double dbl1, double dbl2) {
        return dbl1 + dbl2; // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is definitely a workable approach, a small issue here is that `ConvertSomething` would need to contain the logic from all `convertSomething` methods from the Java implementation, embedded in a cover-all-bases `switch` or `if`/`else`. In addition, this approach makes it impossible to implement `SomeInterface` from OP's example.

Comment: I think I will try this route for now. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:  That's true, but since enums are closed to extension, that doesn't seem like a major shortcoming.  You are guaranteed to know the entire universe of possible values at compile time, unlike the general case with other types.

Comment: @recursive You are absolutely right. That is why I wrote it's a small issue :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this use of enumerations a good practice in Java?

Absolutely. This is exactly the sort of usage that has been envisioned when enumerations where introduced in Java.

> what approach should I take in C#?

Since C# `enum`s do not have the same capability, you would need to model it in some other way. One approach would be defining a class or an interface with the methods from your Java `enum`, and make a bunch of `public readonly` instances mimicking the `enum` entries:

```
public ISomeInterface {
    Func<double,double,double> ConvertSomething {get;}
}

public class ThisIsAnEnum : ISomeInterface {

    public Func<double,double,double> ConvertSomething {get;private set;}

    public MetricType MetricType {get;private set;}

    // Private constructor prevents outside instantiations
    private ThisIsAnEnum(MetricType mt) {
        MetricType = mt;
    }

    public static readonly ThisIsAnEnum TypeKilom = new ThisIsAnEnum(MetricType.Kilometer) {
        ConvertSomething = (dbl1, dbl2) => {
            ...
            return res;
        }
    }

    public static readonly ThisIsAnEnum TypeMillim = new ThisIsAnEnum(MetricType.Millimeter) {
        ConvertSomething = (dbl1, dbl2) => {
            ...
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```

Using `Func<double,double,double>` lets you use a single class with multiple different pieces of logic, while preserving the dispatch based on the instance.

One unfortunate consequence of taking this approach is that you wouldn't be able to `switch` on these `enum`s.

Comment: As a supporting example for "this is a good pattern in Java", look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html, which uses basically the same pattern.