# Using lombok @Getter annotation with Java enum

Tags: java, enums, lombok

I am trying to use an enum as a map to retrieve country names from alpha-2 country codes. I have an enum class like so:

```
public enum Country {
    AF("Afghanistan");

    @Getter
    private final String fullName;

    private Country(String fullName) {
      this.fullName = fullName;
    }

}
```

I would expect that if I instantiated a new Country object like so

```
String country = new Country("AF").getFullName();
```

The variable `country` should be set to  "Afghanistan", but I am getting an error that the object cannot be `Country` cannot be instantiated.

Comment: try `AF.getFullName()` ;) (enum constructors must all be invoked within the enum... ...without "new" keyword!; ... so `AF("Afghanistan")` is the enum(instance) declaration + constructor invocation)

Comment: problem is I would ideally like to use a variable in place of the hardcoded string `String country = new Country(countryCode).getFullName();`.

Comment: Either use `Country.AF`, or `Country.valueOf("AF")`. Also, this has nothing to do with Lombok, you only use that to generate a getter.

Comment: if you want the `AF` Country from the String `"AF"`, you can use: `Country.valueOf("AF")` ..if you need this functionality for full name, you'd have to implement.

Answer (score 1):

check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851422/3874879
Enums cannot be instantiated, they are like a constant, you must define them at compile time, I guess

Answer (score 1):

An enum is a special "class" that represents a group of constants (unchangeable variables, like final variables).

You can access enum constants with the dot syntax:

```
String country = Country.AF.getFullName();
```

Enum constants are public, static and final. You cannot create enum instances using `new`.

Enum constants (`AF` in your case) are the only instances you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object.

Check this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

And try this: `String country = Country.AF.getFullName();`

**EDIT**: If you want to use a variable in place of the hardcoded string you can define some method like `findByCountryCode(countryCode)` in your enum

```
public Country findByCountryCode(String code) {
    for (Country value : Country.values()) {
        if (value.getFullName().equals(code)) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```